# Froala Editor v2 multiple editors Current instance

Tags: froala

Im trying to create a simple custom plugin button that will trigger modal. Here is my code:

```
  $.FE.DefineIcon('mybutton', {
      NAME: 'smile'
  });
  $.FE.RegisterCommand('mybutton', {
      title: 'My Button',
      undo: true,
      focus: true,
      refreshOnCallback: true,
      popup: false,
      callback: function() {
          var editor = this;
          this.selection.save();

          $('#modal').modal('show');
          $('#modal').on('click', 'a', function() {
              editor.selection.restore();
              editor.html.insert('<i class="icon-apple"></i>');
              $(this).modal('hide');
          });
      },
  });
```

The above all works fine, but since I have 3 editors initialized on the same page, all 3 of them get 'icon' inserted. How do I assign to active editor only.

Comment: can you provide a working example about this problem? (jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react or angular, you could use state to set editor and then events like 'initialized' in froala to set editor. This differentiates the various editors in the pages or views.